# Laravel 6 Route not defined

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-6

I'm a little confused on how this is supposed to work. But I'm getting an error:

> Route [review-delete] not defined.

In my web.php I have

```
Route::get('review-delete/{id}', 'CommentController@deleteComment');
```

And in the view file I have:

```
 <a class="dropdown-item review-dropdown-item"
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"
    href="{{ route('review-delete', $comment->id) }}">Delete</a>
```

I'm getting an error telling me the route doesn't exist. I think I'm misunderstanding the docs on this topic.
What am I overlooking here?

Comment: try this href="{{ route('review-delete', [ 'id' => $comment->id]) }}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set name of the router

```
Route::get('review-delete/{id}', 'CommentController@deleteComment')->name('review-delete);
```